# Cocoon First Option Not Saving - Nested Fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, cocoon-gem

I'm using Cocoon for a nested form, however the first set of fields do not save into the database, if I create a second row they seem to save just fine?

I'm guessing its just something I'm overlooking

```
class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :questions
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

---

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :form
end
```

----- form_controller.rb

```
def new
  @form = Form.new
  @form.questions.build
end 

def create
  @form = Form.new(form_params)

  if @form.save
     redirect_to action: "show", id: @form.id
  else
     render('new')
  end
end

def form_params
 params.require(:form).permit(:title, :description, :status, questions_attributes: [:form_id, :question_type, :question_text, :position,   :answer_options, :validation_rules, :done, :_destroy])
end
```

---

```
<%= simple_form_for Form.new ,:url => {:action => :create} do |f| %>
    <div class="section-row"> 
      <div class="section-cell">
        <%= f.label :title, "Form Title" %>
        <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "Form Title" %>
        <br/></br>
        <%= f.label :description, "Form Description" %>
        <%= f.text_area :description, placeholder: "Form Description" %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :status, value: "online" %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-row"> 
      <div class="section-cell">
        <div id="questions">
          <%= simple_fields_for :questions do |question| %>
            <%= render 'question_fields', :f => question %>
            <%= link_to_add_association 'add question', f, :questions %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-row"> 
      <div class="section-cell">
        <%= f.submit "Create Ticket", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

---- _question_fields.html.erb

```
<div class='nested-fields'>
    <%= f.label :question_type, "Question Type" %>
    <%= f.select :question_type, 
options_for_select([['Text Box','textbox'],['Dropdown Options','select'],   ['Mutiple Choice','radio']], params[:question_type]),
{}, { :class => '' } %>
</div>
```

Comment: The only thing I don't see in your code that I have in mine for a similar function is in your _question_fields.html.erb where I do not see the <div class="nested-fields"> wrapper around your inputs.   Otherwise it does look like it should work.

Comment: Thanks For looking Art, yeah really strange issue... I'll keep playing with the code this evening and see if I can find the problem

Comment: I added that Markup but still not good... updated post

Comment: What is posted to the controller? (you can find this in the logfile) to see if the strong parameters definition matches. Do you have validations on `Question` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the `f` in front of the `simple_fields_for` : then the `simple_fields_for` has no knowledge of the form, nor the associations, so it will name the parameters posted to the controller differently, so it will be blocked by your strong parameters definition.

So if you write

```
f.simple_fields_for :questions do |question|
```

it should just work ;)

Smaller remarks:

- the `link_to_add_association` should be outside of the loop, otherwise it will not be visible if there are none, and will be displayed for each question (which may or may not make sense in your UI).
- you should add the `id` inside the strong parameters for `questions_attributes` (important for editing/deleting)

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you so much nathanvda... really appreciate your help with that one.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote the `link_to_add_association` inside the simple_fields_for
you should write your form as follows (as documented):

```
<div id="questions">
<%= f.simple_fields_for :questions do |question| %>
 <%= render 'question_fields', f: => question %>
<% end %>
<div class="links">
 <%= link_to_add_association 'add task', f, :questions %>
</div>
```